# bound on hermitian matrix and triple products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $H $ be a hermitian matrix in complex hilbert with $\Vert H \Vert = K$. I am trying to show the following for any unit vector $v \in S$ and $w \in T$ where $S,T$ are orthogonal, we have $-r_2^2 v^*Hv+2r_1r_2Real(v^*Hw)+r_2^2w^*Hw \geq -2K r_2^2-2Kr_2$.

Edit: $r_1,r_2 $ are real numbers smaller than 1.

Comment: It seems a bit strange that $r_1$ is in the left side of the inequality, but not the right side.

Comment: @irchans yes both $r_1 , r_2$ are less than one so somehow it could be possible to consume one of them inside H

Comment: Is $w$ a unit vector?  When you say $S$ and $T$ are orthogonal, do you mean that "for all $s\in S$ and $t\in T$ the inner product of $s$ and $t$ is zero", or do you mean that "for all $s\in S\cap(S\cap T)^\perp$ and $t\in T\cap(S\cap T)^\perp$ the inner product of $s$ and $t$ is zero"?

Comment: @irchans Yes w is of norm 1. For all s, t s and t are orthogonal.

Comment: Can not $r_2$ be reduced from both the LHS and RHS?